# Don't Misunderstand Me

Tags: riddle, music, sports

> Many claim my creation
>   but I'm thousands of years old.
>
> You can meet me when music is played
>   or during sports activities,
>   actually you can meet me anywhere.
>
> Some use me to show appreciation,
>   some think I'm offensive,
>   others simply think I'm a joke.
>
> Some think I'm evil,
>   some use me to ward off bad luck,
>   for others I'm a part of their spirituality.
>
> Change me a little and some will think I am wrong,
>   but I'll love you anyway.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 8):

What am I?

> The Horns.

Many claim my creation
but I'm thousands of years old.

> Animals have had horns for a while.

You can meet me when music is played
or during sports activities,
actually you can meet me anywhere.

> "Throwing up the horns" for heavy metal, or trumpet-like horns at football matches.

Some use me to show appreciation,
some think I'm offensive,
others simply think I'm a joke.

> There are a variety of opinions of this hand gesture.

Some think I'm evil,
some use me to ward off bad luck,
for others I'm a part of their spirituality.

> "Devil horns" sounds pretty evil. In pop culture, witches tend to use this hand gesture while conjuring.

Change me a little and some will think I am wrong,
but I'll love you anyway.

> Use just your thumb and your pinky and you've got a hand gesture more often interpreted as "I love you" (but also "cowabunga!").

Comment: For sports: there's the `uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Ubbx_%27rz_Ubeaf`. Also, re: being very old: `uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Fvta_bs_gur_ubeaf#/zrqvn/Svyr:Andfu-r_Enwno_-_Xnegve_vafpevcgvba.wct`

Comment: This is very close to the intended answer, but needs a better explanation of the clues. @question_asker has provided some very good links.

Comment: I might fill in more at some point, but I'm happy I was able to get so close without looking anything up on the internet.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I didn't look those up either!

Answer (score 4):

What am I?

> You are a: Star

Many claim my creation but I'm thousands of years old.

> Stars are thousands of years old; there are different theories on how they were formed

You can meet me when music is played

> Rock/Pop stars... Asterisks are also used in musical notation

or during sports activities

> Sports stars... Some scoring notations, e.g. in cricket, also use asterisks

actually you can meet me anywhere

> You can see stars in the sky from anywhere

Some use me to show appreciation

> 5-star rating system: more stars means more appreciation

some think I'm offensive

> Asterisks are used to censor letters in expletives

others simply think I'm a joke

> Asterix comics?

Some think I'm evil,

> Astrology considers some alignments of stars to be unfavourable

some use me to ward off bad luck

> Some lucky charms are star-shaped

for others I'm a part of their spirituality.

> Some religious symbols are stars

Change me a little and some will think I am wrong but I'll love you anyway.

> Removing the horizontal line from an asterisk results in an "X" which indicates "wrong", but is also a sign for a loving kiss ("XOXO")

Don't Misunderstand Me

> Asterisks are used to indicate a correction to a previous line in a chat conversation

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> A Clap

Many claim my creation
but I'm thousands of years old.

> No one knows when clapping started - just that it's gone on forever.

You can meet me when music is played

> People clap during music

or during sports activities,

> Clapping during a sporting event

actually you can meet me anywhere.

> People randomly clap

Some use me to show appreciation,

> You can clap to show you appreciate something that you've obtained or viewed, etc.

some think I'm offensive,

> Some people consider clapping as offensive and as an anxiety trigger.

others simply think I'm a joke.

> Clapping with one hand is considered a joke.

Some think I'm evil,

> In Bhutan, clapping is considered a way to call evil, so it is considered an evil act.

some use me to ward off bad luck,

> Some cultures use clapping to ward off bad luck

for others I'm a part of their spirituality.

> Clapping your hands is part of worship for some denominations of Christianity.

Change me a little and some will think I am wrong,
but I'll love you anyway.

I don't know on that one.

Comment: Nope, your answer must match all the lines.

Comment: Yes, I was still adding pieces.

Comment: I'm surprised you found so many matches, but as you see, the last part is missing. In addition some of the clues have far more concrete explanations (for the answer I have in mind).

Comment: Worth a try =D - Amusingly, I only looked up the ones about creation and Bhutan.  I knew the others, offhand.  Why do I know so much about clapping?

Comment: This was the first thing that came to my mind.  I'm curious what could fit the clues better.

Comment: I have yet to even hear about anyone *genuinely* thinking your "offensive" thing

Answer (score 3):

You are a

> **Smile**

Many claim my creation
but I'm thousands of years old.

> People say "I put a smile on his face", but did someone really create/ put a smile? It has always been there.

You can meet me when music is played
or during sports activities,
actually you can meet me anywhere.

> We can spot/ meet a smile anywhere. Let it be while music is being played or any sport activity. We can see smiles literally anywhere.

Some use me to show appreciation,
some think I'm offensive,
others simply think I'm a joke.

> Smiles with nods are used to show appreciations. On some occasions a smile might be offensive (e.g. Funerals) also smirking can be thought to be offensive. A joke is the simplest reason for a smile.

Some think I'm evil,
some use me to ward off bad luck,
for others I'm a part of their spirituality.

> Evil grin is also a kind of smile. Smiles can get you out of bad situations/ luck. Spirituality is often means to find happiness and thus is strongly associated with smiles.

Change me a little and some will think I am wrong,
but I'll love you anyway.

> Smirking is a type of smile that can lead to an impression of being wrong but a smile is always lovely.

What am I?

> A smile

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> Art

Many claim my creation
but I'm thousands of years old.

> Art's been around for a very long time, and you could say the artists/composers/writers and buyers of the works, etc claim it.

You can meet me when music is played
or during sports activities,
actually you can meet me anywhere.

> You can meet Art anywhere - Art can be interpreted to be many things. Music is an Art, and sports could be considered to be an Art too. Many man made structures can be considered to be Art (eg. architecture)

Some use me to show appreciation,
some think I'm offensive,
others simply think I'm a joke.

> As Art can be interpreted to be many things, there can be many reactions to it. Appreciation is the most noted reaction, although some may find Art (especially Modern Art) offensive or a joke.

Some think I'm evil,
some use me to ward off bad luck,
for others I'm a part of their spirituality.

> Stravinsky's Rite of Spring is an example of where some may think the Art is evil. When it was first performed, the audience thought it was the work of the Devil (or something like that). Charms can be considered as a form of Art which can are used by some to ward off bad luck. Art can be considered spiritual... perhaps hymns/church music?

Change me a little and some will think I am wrong,
but I'll love you anyway.

> In music, teachers often go on about how we should retain "fidelity" to the work and not change anything. However, others may disagree which may leave it up to interpretation.

Comment: Sorry, but the intended answer is a little more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> God.

Many claim my creation

> Many religions have been created and all (most?) claim to be the right one.

but I'm thousands of years old.

> Records of religion goes back a few thousand years.

You can meet me when music is played

> Religious songs or music played at churches, etc.

or during sports activities,

> The US national anthem, played before the onset of any sports, contains a reference to God.

actually you can meet me anywhere.

> Images/references/quotes/temples of God can be found wherever you look.

Some use me to show appreciation,

> "Thank God for that".

some think I'm offensive,

> Some people don't like having the idea of God forced down their throat, e.g., claiming there can be no morality with God.

others simply think I'm a joke.

> Many people are just not convinced of the evidence for the existence of God and find the idea ridiculous.

Some think I'm evil,

> Representations of capricious entities, who are willing to exact punishment towards anyone who doesn't follow the Law. Or simply an all-powerful God who doesn't bother to make all suffering go away.

some use me to ward off bad luck,

> Praying for things to go well.

for others I'm a part of their spirituality.

> Not all religions/spiritual philosophies focus around a deity, but many do.

Change me a little and some will think I am wrong,

> There can be various denominations of a single religion, which mostly have few differences among themselves, yet each one considers the others wrong.

but I'll love you anyway.

> The god of Christianity loves you regardless of what you do.

Possible bonus

> The title "Don't Misunderstand Me" might also be a reference to God, seen how there can be many interpretation of religious texts, which can create some ambiguities and misunderstandings of his intentions.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the intended answer. You also mix G.. and r......., the intended answer is one specific thing.

Comment: *The US national anthem, played before the onset of any sports, contains a reference to God.* - Umm, no it doesn't.  Unless you mean "America the Beautiful", but the national anthem is the "Star Spangled Banner", which contains no such references.